# Fetch Current Schema name in Postgres Function

Tags: postgresql, function, variables, schema, plpgsql

I am trying to write a function in Postgres pgsql where I need to capture the schema name where this function is created in a variable let say VAR within the function and then "set search_path to VAR" and then continue with the logic in the  function , My question is how can i populate the schema name programatically to the schema name with in the Function body into a variable and then use that variable to set the search_path to the current schema ? Also is there any alternate way to do it ?

Thanks

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve with that?

Comment: what is happening is that in my function I am referencing certain tables in the function body , i am noticing is that when I run the procedure post deployment the function is not able to locte the tables though they exist in the schema ,i am getting "relation doesnot exit error", thus my idea is to set search_path to the current schema and then write my remaining code logic in the function.

Comment: "*set search_path to the current schema*" makes no sense. The "current schema" **is** the "search path"

Comment: Not sure why the "relation doesnot exit error" is coming up even though the tables exist in the schema

Answer (score 0):

Postgres has not current schema. But you can set `search_path` per function - like

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION foo()
RETURNS void AS $$
BEGIN
  ...
END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql SET search_path = 'xxx';
```

Comment: @ptilloo - if you want. There is not other practical possibility. Postgres is very static environment.

Comment: I am logging in the Database as an underprevlidged user , I am trying to run a FUNCTION which needs me to quality the schema name to the table , is there a way i can grab the schema name in a variable and prefix the table name with that variable in the FUNCTION  Code else set search path to the schema name on the fly in the Function code

Comment: @ptilloo - you can use dynamic SQL - see plpgsql statement `EXECUTE`.  Then you can write `EXECUTE format('select * from %I.table', 'yourschema') ...`, but it is obscure solution - maybe you has some broken design